# Quadratic equations - finding value of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Question:
Solve the equation $$\frac{2x}{3x^2 - x+2} - \frac{7x}{3x^2 + 5x+2} = 1$$

I attempted to split the two quadratic equations into their roots, however, was unable to do so. Then I tried to solve by multiplying and removing the denominator, but the process became very cumbersome. Any easier way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure the first denominator isn't $3x^2 - x - 2$?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it isn't. I think it might be a misprint on the side of the exam itself. It would definitely make the question much easier :/

Answer (score 3):

Setting $A=3x^2-x+2$ gives you
$$\begin{align}\frac{2x}{A}-\frac{7x}{A+6x}=1&\iff 2x(A+6x)-7xA=A(A+6x), A\not=0,A+6x\not =0\\&\iff A^2+11Ax-12x^2=0, A\not=0,A+6x\not =0\\&\iff (A+12x)(A-x)=0, A\not=0,A+6x\not =0\end{align}$$

Comment: And........ What to do after that? We have to find the value of x right?

Comment: @Gummybears: You can solve it because $(A+12x)(A-x)=0\iff A+12x=0 \ \text{or}\  A-x=0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So we are only coming up with two plausible solutions.

Comment: @Gummybears: I think you'll have two real solutions and two complex solutions.

Comment: Yep, so I basically disregarded the complex solutions.

Comment: @Gummybears: Is there anything unclear? If you have, let me know it.

Comment: Nope. That's an awesome way to do it I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @Gummybears: You are welcome! P.S. I like your questions:)

Comment: lol I have a lot more. How are you with circles?

Comment: @Gummybears: Sorry, but I don't get what you mean...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16741/discussion-between-gummy-bears-and-mathlove).